# I have used the post method still I get the error

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

```html
                            <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail"  method="POST"  >
<div class="row gtr-uniform">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdseqkZAAAAAL5m2SpQL1I5Wo5aoC9qcWrfFq7c"></div>
    <!-- Break -->
    <div class="col-12">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Break -->
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="primary" /></li>
            <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
        </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="google.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="_autoresponse" value="Your message has been recieved.Thank You...">  
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I have the method="POST" attribute in the form. I have used formsubmit.co to get help with the backend stuff, but it keeps giving me an error that "Form should POST". How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you serving this from a web server?

Comment: Is your formsubmit url correct? Looks like you're posting to the root route of your profile. Is there a a specific location you should post to, such as "/posts" or "/api" ?

Comment: @itsanewabstract yes it is right

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_url" value="https://yourdomain.co/contact.html"> You can use this hidden input with your form submission because formsubmit.co required this input with the form.

Comment: Running this on jsFiddle results in _"Check Your Email
This form needs Activation. We've sent you an email containing an 'Activate Form' link. Just click it and your form will be actived!"_

Comment: @j08691 I have already done that.

Comment: I'm just tell you what I see

Comment: Consider removing your email in public forums such as this. dubeyrohit1999@gmail.com looks like your email, based on your stack overflow name.

Comment: @J.Ko Thank You, I will.

Answer (score 0):

When using your snippet above, I get the following message: "*Make sure you open this page through a web server, FormSubmit will not work in pages browsed as HTML files.*" Have you read [the FAQ](https://formsubmit.co/help) on this **exact** error message?

According to the linked FAQ:

> You may encounter an error: Make sure you open this page through a web
> server, FormSubmit will not work in pages browsed as HTML files.
>
> So there are 2 ways you can fix this issue.
>
> You can use a simple web server like Apache HTTP Server. You can add a
> hidden input field with the form URL,
>
> ```
> <input type="hidden" name="_url" value="https://yourdomain.co/contact.html">
> ```

Comment: I tried what you said and ended up on the same page which said, "Form should POST", Make sure your form has the method="POST" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I'm sure it will help you out.

I'm referring to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719964/9535043

Your code seems okay the only issue is with the "_next" feature. As FormSubmit documentation clearly mentioned you have to provide an alternative URL not just a path or domain name, it should be a URL.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://yourdomain.co/thanks.html">
```

I'm sure this will help you out.

> Further information
>
> FormSubmmit Documentation: https://formsubmit.co/documentation