# FormSubmit says my form should use method=POST but it actually does

Tags: html, forms

I'm using FormSubmit to create a contact form in my static website (hosted on a server).

My form looks like this:

```
<div id="contact-area" class="container">
      <h1>~$ contactme</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="https://formsubmit.co/c379c266434ca1a039bdf03209919395" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name..." required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your e-mail" required>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <textarea maxlength="1000" placeholder="Your message..." class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="_template" value="table">
          <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none">
          <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
          <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="message_sent.html">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

My email is verified. When the user clicks on submit button, this message appears in a new page:

" Make sure your form has the method="POST" attribute "

However, I receive the message. That's weird. Anyone know why it says my form should have POST attribute while my form actually has the post attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet is all okay. I have tested it, forms are getting submitted, and nothing wrong except the way you implement the "_next" feature. As FormSubmit documentation clearly mentioned you have to provide an alternative URL not just a path or file, it should be a URL.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://yourdomain.co/thanks.html">
```

Please change the hidden filed in your form to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://yourdomain.co/message_sent.html">
```

and that should probably work fine.

> Additional information:
>
> FormSubmit documentation: https://formsubmit.co/documentation

Comment: is it not possible to not have the _next at all? What if i just want to stay in the same spot on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was adding gtag conversion return code to the button. Remove the return code, remover the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have gone wrong in the `action` of the form.

Try using this:

```html
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
<!-- Your form inputs here -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for this error is having a forward slash after your email in the action of the form, as I did.

Example of my mistake:

```
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com/" method="POST">
```

I removed the `/` after `@email.com` and naturally, it worked fine.